# How do I make the "<AppName> Would Like to Send You Notifications" permissions dialog localized on the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, localization, internationalization

I set my iOS Simulator (13.5) to German language for my app, which is fully localized:

[image]

But when I start my app up, I still get this dialog in English when asking for notification privileges:

[image]

I thought my Info.plist was fully localized. What am I missing here to make this dialog appear in German?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug with Apple about this problem. Apple recently got back to me and said they’ve fixed it in Xcode 14 (with iOS 16). I’ve gone ahead and tested and confirmed that Xcode 14 does indeed fix it.

Comment: I have same issue with my app. I'm on iOS 16, and xcode 14 but still for notification permission dialog is in english only when I change app's preferred language in settings

Comment: On device or on simulator?

Comment: on both simulator and device. I found that changing preferred language doesn't affect notification permission. it only works when you change whole OS language

Comment: File another bug with Apple. Mine bug was specifically related to "whole OS language".